# how to create a Share Intent for an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imageview, share

I am creating a photo application where the user selects and image from the gallery and it displays in an imageview in the center of the app. How would I go about creating a share intent for the ImageView?

**UPDATE**
Share intent is working, however, the image can not be shared because I can not save it to the path I have selected. Below is my code. Any help?

```
public void taptoshare(View v)
    {  
        View content = findViewById(R.id.myimage);
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
            File file = new File("/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
            try 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri phototUri = Uri.parse("/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
        shareIntent.setData(phototUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, phototUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via"));

}
```

}

Comment: do you want to share image or want to pick image from native gallery?

Comment: I want to share the image which is displayed in the ImageView (a photo the user selected from the gallery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri phototUri = Uri.parse(path);
shareIntent.setData(photootUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photootUri);
getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Use this for sharing"));
```

Comment: The share intent works great! But, how do i save the image in my imageview to disk? The menu pops up and everything to share but fails because it can not find the specified path.

Comment: You need to save the image from the camera application. Then you can pass that file path uri in the share intent. http://www.technotalkative.com/android-pick-image-from-native-gallery/

Answer (score 1):

See the below link. it will very helpful for u. I think it satisfied your requirement.

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-pick-image-from-native-gallery/

Comment: This actually helped me with my memory allocation issue.. thanks!